# Python Script to manage dns in Active Directory

Tags: python, dns, active-directory

What I want to do is write an Application in Python and deploy it in django(I want to implement it on Linux platform), and that Application could manage DNS remotely in Active Directory(Windows environment).
It's preferred that all the scripts written in Cpython.
I tryed several ways below but failed:

1. Use a module called dnspython, but it seem only work with BIND DNS, that still doesn't support Window DNS.
2. Use pywin32 module to invoke WMI, but pywin32 is a module only for Windows platform and failed to work in Linux.
3. Use Ironpython, it is the only workaround I get, but not so good because all other applications will be in Cpython.

Can somebody provide a resolution? Or a workaround.

In my understand, I need a cpython scripts run in Linux that could remotely manage DNS in Active Directory on Windows platform.
If there is any problem about it, please let me know.
Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What sorts of DNS operations do you want to perform? It would change what direction I'd point you in...

Answer (score 1):

Set up the windows machine as a chaching nameserver, with the linux box as its authoritative nameserver. That way you can just change the settings of BIND on the linux box, and the windows box should follow along.

This question probably belongs on [server fault](https://serverfault.com/), though.